# box2d collision not registered everytime

Tags: c++, box2d, game-physics

i am making an endless runner type of game in which the player jumps based on a isgrounded variable which is set to true when the player begins collision with the ground object which is itself a static body . the player(dynamic body) comprises of 2 fixtures , one main and one at the bottom(sensor) for grounding detection .. the bottom fixture is assigned a user data of 4
and i have my collision listener somewhat like this

```
class coldetect : public b2ContactListener
{
virtual void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
{
    groundplayer(contact);
}
void groundplayer(b2Contact* contact);
};

void coldetect::groundplayer(b2Contact* contact)
{
if((int)contact->GetFixtureA()->GetUserData() == 4)
    {
        std::cout<<"grounded\n";
        static_cast<player*>(contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody()->GetUserData())->isGrounded();
    }
    else if((int)contact->GetFixtureB()->GetUserData() == 4)
    {
        std::cout<<"grounded\n";
        static_cast<player*>(contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody()->GetUserData())->isGrounded();
    }
}
```

which should call is grounded wheneve the bottom part collides with any thing like the ground or obstacles etc ..  that is happening but sometimes the collision is not registered so the player does not jump and is stuck 
what can be workaround for this ??

Comment: This would only work if the bottom sensor is the only thing in the world that has a user data set to 4. Assuming that is the case, it looks ok to me. If that's not the case, when the bottom sensor touches something else that is set to 4, the isGrounded could be called on the something else instead.

Comment: yup only the bottom sensor has the user data set to 4 .. moreover the problem arises only after the player jumps off an obstacle like a crate and not otherwise .. like it will jump off the crate and after when it jumps off from the ground next time ONLY then this seem to occur

Comment: So there is only one fixture in the world with a user data set to 4, and yet when it contacts something you don't see that "grounded" display printed to stdout? Doesn't seem possible. Are you changing any collision filter settings during the simulation? Remember these contact callbacks will be called inside the world Step function, so you need to call that if you want to get callbacks.

Comment: no i am not using any collision filters .. by calling the step function if u mean calling world.step() .. of course i am calling that in my main loop .. the problem occurs only sometimes after the player has jumped off a crate ... otherwise it runs fine ..